# When update database I don't want update all columns

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

When update database I don't want update all columns, update only if I have filled `<input/>`

Now with my code when I do submit data to database if input is empty I got update that column in db with 0 and lost previusly data. How to fix that? If is input empty don't send any data to db.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "medvedgrad";

// First we create the connection
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$mysql_host .";dbname=".$mysql_database.";charset=utf8", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$zm = $data->zlatni_medvjed;
$ck = $data->crna_kraljica;
$gv = $data->gricka_vjestica;
$dk = $data->dva_klasa;
$fk = $data->fakin;

// Then we prepare, and execute the query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `stanje_piva` SET `zlatni_medvjed`=`zlatni_medvjed`+:zm, `crna_kraljica`=`crna_kraljica`+:ck, `gricka_vjestica`=`gricka_vjestica`+:gv, `dva_klasa`=`dva_klasa`+:dk,`fakin`=`fakin`+:fk WHERE `id`=1");
$stmt->execute(array("zm" => $zm, "ck" => $ck, "gv" => $gv, "dk" => $dk, "fk" => $fk));
?>
```

Here is my angular controller

```
 angular.module('angularLoginApp')
.controller('UnosUSkladisteCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.insertdata = function(){
        $http.post("database/unos-piva.php", {'zlatni_medvjed':$scope.zlatni_medvjed, 'crna_kraljica':$scope.crna_kraljica, 'gricka_vjestica':$scope.gricka_vjestica, 'dva_klasa':$scope.dva_klasa, 'fakin':$scope.fakin })
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log("Podaci uspiješno spremljeni");
            alert("Nove količine piva su dodane u skladište");
        });
    }

    $scope.data = {message: "Molimo vas da točno navedete što unosite u skladište"};

});
```

HTML

```
 <form class="form-horizontal col-xs-12" col-sm-12" name="signUpForm" ng-submit="submitFormSignUp()" novalidate>

                <!-- Zlatni medvjed -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label no-padding-right " for="zlatni_medvjed">Zlatni medvjed boca 0.5l</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">  
                            <input ng-model="zlatni_medvjed" ng-change="doCheck()" placeholder="Količina boca 0.5l" type="number"  class="form-control">                        
                        </span>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Crna kraljica -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label no-padding-right " for="crna_kraljica">Crna kraljica boca 0.5l</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">  
                            <input ng-model="crna_kraljica" placeholder="Količina boca 0.5l" type="number"  class="form-control">                        
                        </span>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Grička vještica -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label no-padding-right " for="gricka_vjestica">Grička vještica boca 0.5l</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">  
                            <input ng-model="gricka_vjestica" placeholder="Količina boca 0.5l" type="number"  class="form-control">                        
                        </span>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Dva klasa -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label no-padding-right " for="dva_klasa">Dva klasa boca 0.5l</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">  
                            <input ng-model="dva_klasa" placeholder="Količina boca 0.5l" type="number"  class="form-control">                        
                        </span>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fakin -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label no-padding-right " for="fakin">Fakin boca 0.5l</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">  
                            <input ng-model="fakin" placeholder="Količina boca 0.5l" type="number"  class="form-control">                        
                        </span>   
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button ng-click="insertdata()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Unesi količine u skladište</button>
                    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send a single object rather than manually setting each property of the object in the $http.post function.

```
angular.module('angularLoginApp')
.controller('UnosUSkladisteCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.form = {};

$scope.insertdata = function(){
    $http.post("database/unos-piva.php", $scope.form)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("Podaci uspiješno spremljeni");
        alert("Nove količine piva su dodane u skladište");
    });
}

$scope.data = {message: "Molimo vas da točno navedete što unosite u skladište"};

});
```

Then in your form html make your ng-model="" access property of the form object like this:

```
<input ng-model="form.zlatni_medvjed" ng-change="doCheck()" placeholder="Količina boca 0.5l" type="number"  class="form-control">
```

You should have null values sent to the server when you do it this way.
You can also check in the dev console on the network tab if it is really sending 0 to the server or if it sending null and the server is saving 0 to the db.

---

**EDIT**

The problem is this:

```
//Then we prepare, and execute the query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `stanje_piva` SET `zlatni_medvjed`=`zlatni_medvjed`+:zm, `crna_kraljica`=`crna_kraljica`+:ck, `gricka_vjestica`=`gricka_vjestica`+:gv, `dva_klasa`=`dva_klasa`+:dk,`fakin`=`fakin`+:fk WHERE `id`=1");
$stmt->execute(array("zm" => $zm, "ck" => $ck, "gv" => $gv, "dk" => $dk, "fk" => $fk));
```

If you are setting the values every time without checking to see if there is a value, you will always lose the previous data, even if the value is null (hence the updated value will be null).

Comment: Also check and make sure your db columns are nullable

Comment: it sends 'null'

Comment: I've edited my answer. You may be better off getting the original values from the db and populating the form on page load that way you won't have null values if the user did not edit anything.